# Given $f$ holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ and $|f(z)|\sin(1-|z|) \leq C$, $C>0$ prove the following inequalities

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$, and $C>0$ so that $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$:

$$|f(z)|\sin(1-|z|) \leq C$$

Prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$|f^{(n)}(0)| \leq Cn! \frac{2}{(1-r)r^n} \forall r\in (0,1)$$

and then prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$|f^{(n)}(0)| \leq 2Cn! \frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)}}{n^n}$$

So far I have sen that if $z \in \mathbb{D}$ it0s true that $0<\sin(1-|z|) <1$ so by Cauchy's estimate:

$$|f^{(n)}(0)|\leq n!\frac{C}{\sin(1-|r|)r^n}, \forall r \in (0,1)$$

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \sin (1-|z|)=1 \Rightarrow |f^{(n)}(0)|\leq n!\frac{C}{r^n} \Rightarrow |f^{(n)}(0)|\leq n!\frac{C}{(1-r)r^n} \leq n!\frac{2C}{(1-r)r^n}$$

But then what's the point of that 2, I must have made a mistake somewhere. And how should I tackle the second part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the sine is concave upward on $[0,1]$, $\sin(x) \ge \sin(1)x$ for $0 \le x \le 1$. Since $\sin(1) > \sin(\pi/6) = 1/2$, then $\sin(x) > (1/2)x$ for $0 < x < 1$. Thus

$$\frac{1}{\sin(1-r)} < \frac{2}{1-r},\quad r\in (0,1)$$

This estimate is what you need to get the desired inequality in the first part. To solve the second part, set $r = \frac{n}{n+1}$ in the first part.